# Computing Min-Cut of a Graph with No Reverse Edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, edges

I know you can use a Max-Flow algorithm like Ford-Fulkerson and find a Min-Cut with the Max-Flow/Min-Cut theorem.  However, this is not exactly the type of Min-Cut I need to compute.

I want to find the Min-Cut of graph G into sets S and T, where there are ***no edges from T to S***.

This example graph finds a min-cut (of magnitude 250), but the result has an edge from T to S (the red one).

[image]

Does anyone know if there's an existing algorithm to solve this?  Or if there's a way to modify my flow network so I can use something like Ford-Fulkerson?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a different problem that I've manipulated into a graph partitioning one.  It has a constraint that one set must only receive data from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work: For every edge, add a reverse edge with infinite capacity. That way if the min-cut is finite, original edges can only go from S to T, not the other way round.

Comment: I think that might work!  It works for this example at least, It places p1 and q1 in S and then we find the min-cut of the bottom 3 edges (still magnitude 250).